# Echo a single variable returned in data object via AJAX Success

Tags: php, json, ajax

I realize this is close to other questions. I simply can;t find the answer.

I have an onclick event that successfully fires an AJAX POST to PHP.
The Data are returned successfully in an encoded_json array.

```
function upvote(str,str2) {
---do a bunch of stuff  
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
    data: {"action": "post_my func", "voted_item":theItemid,"vote_value":currentvote, "vote_type":"upvote"},

    success: function(data){
    var result = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data)
    //console.log(result[2])
    //alert(result[2]);
    jQuery('#newtexthere').html(data);  
    
        }                 
    });     
}
```

I can echo it. I know it's there. The console.log(data) and console.log(result) look like this:

```
{"rowcount":"18","result":"6"}
```

All I want to do is echo a part of this array in *#newtexthere* as in

```
<p id="newtexthere">
*18*
</p>
```

Any and all help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Maybe `result.rowcount`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're extremely close. You need to access the individual properties of the `result` object. You can do so by placing a period after the object name and then specifying a property.

```
jQuery('#newtexthere').html(result.rowcount);
```

Note: this only works after you parse the JSON.

In your sample, you try to access the data with array syntax (`result[2]`) which won't work here because the result variable is an "object" which for now is essentially a group of variables. Accessing object properties is typically done with a period in JS, though you could also get to it with `result['rowcount']`, though most people will typically use the dot syntax.

Comment: Thank you @Riley. I sear I tired this...but perhaps it was before I parsed the JSON as in _var result = JSON.parse(data);_. You rock!